# File type and size 13.1

Tags: 13.10

What  type of file should I make the partitions, what size should I make them and do I need a storage partition for a total of 3. 1-OS Partition, 2-Swap Partition, and 3-Storage Partition?

Comment: Are you talking about 1 partition for /root (operating system), one for SWAP, and one for /home?

Answer (score 0):

> What type of file should I make the partitions,

ext4

> what size should I make them

Whatever you want but I would suggest at least 10 Gb for `/`, but more if you intend to use MySQL and want to use /etc for the storage of databases. Depending on how you use the system you can have no swap or 2x the size of your memory.

*I* myself also create a 25Gb `/home` partition and put the remainder on a separate partition so I can store my personal files there and can always format home.